# How to avoid default value in MutableStateFlow kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I am using MutableStateFlow in my project. When we initialise the MutableStateFlow object we need to give default value.

```
val topics = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
```

when I collect this value

```
[null, "Hello", "world"]
```

I want to pass this list in adapter . So is there a way we can remove the null object before passing in adapter or Is there any better way ?

```
viewModel.topics.collect { topicsList ->
    println(topicsList)         // [null, "Hello", "world"]
    adapter.submitList(topicsList)
}
```

Comment: Seems to me that the null-value comes from the list that you are pushing to the `MutableStateFlow`, not from the `MutableStateFlow` itself.

Comment: It's strange that the list contains `null`, in the definition it shouldn't contain `null`: `MutableStateFlow<List<String>>`

Comment: Yes I know that, So what could I do instead of emptylist()?

Comment: `emptyList` provides an empty list, not `null` object, you need to look to where you set new state to `topics`.

Comment: Is this **exactly** the code you use and **exactly** the output you observe? I ask because `println()` in Kotlin usually does not enclose string values in quotation marks, so your output doesn't seem right at all. Maybe you have e.g. string `"null"` in the list, but it's hard to guess if something seems wrong with your examples.

Comment: oh my bad, I am setting null in my list. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want it to have an enforced initial value, use MutableSharedFlow instead. If you give it `replay = 1`, `onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST`, and `distinctUntilChanged()`, it's basically the same thing as a MutableStateFlow without the enforced `value`. And if `onBufferOverflow` is not `BufferOverflow.SUSPEND`, `tryEmit` will always succeed so you can use `tryEmit()` instead of `value =` .

```
private val _topics = MutableSharedFlow<List<String>>(
    replay = 1,
    onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
)
val topics: Flow<List<String>> = _topics.distinctUntilChanged()

// emitting to the shared flow:
_topics.tryEmit(newValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it emits a list of strings you could try to initialise the StateFlow with a null like so

```
val topics = MutableStateFlow<List<String>?>(null)
```

And when you collect you can check if the emitted value is null or not

```
viewModel.topics.collect { topicsList ->
    topicsList?.let { safeTopics ->
        adapter.submitList(safeTopics)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore initial value of StateFlow, set initial value `null` or anything you want. Then you can use `filter` function on flow.

For example initial value is `null`

```
launch {
    val topicsState = MutableStateFlow<List<String?>?>(null)

    topicsState.filterNotNull().map { topics -> topics.filterNotNull() }.onEach { topics ->
        println(topics)
    }.launchIn(this)

    launch {
        delay(1000)
        topicsState.update { listOf(null, "Hello", "world") }
    }
}
```

Output

```
[Hello, world]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we have given a common generic type sealed class.

**Common Sealed Class**

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val error: String? = null) {
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data = data)
    class Error<T>(error: String) : Resource<T>(error = error)
}
```

In that case, we can set the initial value like this.

```
private val _mutableStateFlow: MutableStateFlow<Resource<List<PackageModel>>?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
```

**PackageModel** is Model/Pojo class

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ignore the first value by using `drop(1)` :

```
viewModel.topics.drop(1).collect { topicsList ->
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
val sampleList = listOf(null, "Hello", "world")
val topics = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(sampleList.filer { it != null })
```